# Setting up on prem agent similar to MS hosted configuration

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to setup my on-prem Ubuntu agent. From [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md) I know the list of software that is installed on such cloud agent machines.

I am keen to know what is the best way for me to mimic such a configuration for my on prem hosted agent. Are there any templates or setup instructions available?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Chubsdad Did you check out the installer scripts, how did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is not template to mimic the MS hosted agent on your local machine. You may need to manually install the softwares. But you can easily installed the softwares by checking out the intaller scripts [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/tree/master/images/linux/scripts/installers).

MS hosted agent machines installed a broad range of tools and softwares to meet all kinds of users' building requirements. And I think there is no need to install on your on-prem agent machine all the tools and softwares on the MS hosted agent machine. You only need to install the necessary softwares that needed for building your pipelines.

You can aslo check document [Azure Pipelines VM image generation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation) to get the Azure Pipelines VM image. And you can also check this document [Build your own Hosted VSTS Agent Cloud](https://wouterdekort.com/2018/02/25/build-your-own-hosted-vsts-agent-cloud-part-1-build/)